# Android - How to save a canvas to an image in internal memory

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Hi I am making an Android app that allows a user to draw on screen. I have a button, when pressed I want the canvas to save as an image into the internal memory. I have tried the following codes but I keep getting `FileNotFoundException open failed: EACCES (permission denied)`:

```
        String path = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(path+"image.png");

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100,200,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        FileOutputStream ostream;

        try {
            ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try context.openFileInput(String fileName) to create fileoutputstream.

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, context.openFileInput(fileName);
```

Comment: The method openFileOutput(String, int) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: @Poensvah it's `openFileInput(String)`, and for `openFileOutput(String, int)` you want to choose a mode, which is an int constant.

Answer (score 0):

in this part try to change to this:

```
File file = new File(path + File.separator + "image.png");
```

and make sure you have these in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```